# HttpServletResponse confirm client received response

Tags: java, servlets

I have an Android app which does several data sync to a Java Servlet and I need to make sure the response is delivered to the Android device before commiting changes to the database.

The problem right now is that a user sends a request, the server makes some changes, commits them and then sends a response back to the user. Sometimes the user never receives the response (unreliable network) and then after a while the user sends the same request again (now I have duplicated data).

I don't need to know if the Android process the response correctly, I just need to make sure he receives the response.

How do I make sure the client received the response?

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String data = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(data);
    Transaction trx = new Transaction(true);
    JSONObject responseJson = SyncService.processSync(trx, dataJson);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(responseJson.toString());
    // Here the transaction to the database is commited regardless if the client receives response (no error thrown)
    trx.commit();
    trx.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you following ways and the last one is my favourite :

1. block the Android UI until the response is received which may be not what you want
2. since you mentioned you don't need the client to parse the response, do what you are doing in a thread in servlet to respond faster and don't block the client

   ```
   new Thread(()->{
   String data =    
   IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
   JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(data);
   Transaction trx = new Transaction(true);
   JSONObject responseJson =  SyncService.processSync(trx, dataJson);
   }).start();
   ```
3. keep track of your requests in android with etag
4. don't use http, instead use **GRPC** protocol which gives you a bidirectional connection between your android and server